# Terminate One Future Upon Completion of Another in Python

Tags: python, ui-automation, concurrent.futures, android-uiautomator

I am currently working with the concurrent.futures and uiautomator2 library in Python to automate UI interactions on an Android device for WhatsApp. In my scenario, I want to automate the process of sending a WhatsApp message.

I have two separate UI interaction tasks using futures.
One for "Send_btn xpath" finding and another for "Ok_btn xpath" finding.

Also, this is sure that if "Send xpath found" then "Ok future will keep on stuck trying to find" As contact is available on whatsapp and there is message in testbox it will have a send btn and no popup.

And if "Ok" found then "Send future will keep on stuck trying to find". As contact is not available on whatsapp then it will have okay btn to close popup and no send btn.

Now, I want is to if anyone of the future complete, I want to immediatly terminate other future too even if it's still running to reduce the long waiting time.
However, I'm encountering difficulties in terminating another task.

If it's not possible please guide me with another possible solution.

```
import uiautomator2 as ui2
import concurrent.futures

def decide_event(_xpath, device):
    try:
        device(resourceId=_xpath).click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

serial = 'RZ8R31TJ21B'
device = ui2.connect(serial)

PHONE_NUMBER = '91xxxxxxxxxx'
MESSAGE = 'Hello World!'

device.shell(["am", "start", "-a", "android.intent.action.VIEW", "-d", f"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={PHONE_NUMBER}&text={MESSAGE}"])

send_btn = "com.whatsapp:id/conversation_entry_action_button"
okay_btn = "android:id/button1"

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    future_send = executor.submit(decide_event, send_btn, device)
    future_okay = executor.submit(decide_event, okay_btn, device)`
```

I tried `Event.set()` unfortunatly it didn't worked. Not sure if I had implemented it in right way.